# My useState in React/NEXTjs is not appending the result from a socket.io event from the server, just overwriting it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, next.js

Frameworks used: **Next.js, Socket.io, React**

I am making a simple messaging app. I am basically just emitting a message someone types, sending that message to the server, which is then "broadcasted" back through an event called "receive-chat-message". The issue I'm having is when the response is handled on the front end with "receive-chat-message", the [messages] state is not appending a new message to display, it's just overwriting the state.

**My goal is to send a message to the server; the server then sends the message back to the client. I then append the new message on the client, sent from the server, to the [messages] state on the client, and then render the state of [messages]. The problem is it's only overwriting the [messages] state, and not appending new messages to it.**

Code that sends message to the server

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitMessage = async () => {
    // socket.io
    const socket = io();
    socket.emit("send-chat-message", message, user);
    setMessage("");
  };
```

Front-End Code

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io();
    socket.on("receive-chat-message", handleSetMessage);

    return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, []);

  const handleSetMessage = (data) => {
    /* data prop is the new message - it has a {message: "message", user: "name"} 
       sent from server.
       THIS IS THE PROBLEM IN THE CODE WHERE IT DOESN'T APPEND
       NEW MESSAGES TO THE [messages] STATE, IT JUST OVERWRITES
       THE CURRENT STATE WITH THE NEW MESSAGE. */

    setMessages([...messages, data]);
  };
```

Back-End Code

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (!res.socket.server.io) {
      const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
      res.socket.server.io = io;

      io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
        socket.on("send-chat-message", async (message, user) => {
          socket.broadcast.emit("recieve-chat-message", 
          {
            message,
            name: user && user.name,
          });
        });
      });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the variables "messages" and "data" inside the function *handleSetMessage*? Just to check if the messages array is not empty when you are trying to append one new message. Did you check if this component is destroyed and recreated with empty state for some reason/logic from parent component? The hook that has the socket io instance runs once? I mean, if this component is recreated for some reason, your hook is running again and again, and your messages is possiblly always empty.

Comment: Thank you bro I figured it out and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting messages through the functional method like:

```
setMessages((messages) => [...messages, data]);
```

Instead of:

```
setMessages([...messages, data])
```

I think we need this because I was updating the state from a function called within a socket.io listener and was never actually grabbing the previous state; so I had to direct it to the previous state and then merge the values.